# how to clear fileupload text box inside a modal popup window in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

If user has selected the file but did not upload and hid the popup, the selected file should disappear (in other words fileupload textbox should be again showing "No File selected" )

```
 $('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var fu = document.getElementById("fileupload1");
        if (fu != null) {
            document.getElementById("fileupload1").outerHTML = fu.outerHTML;
        }
    })
    </script>
```

this code isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modalPopup1', function (event) {
        $("#fileUpload1").val("");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `val("")`:

```
$('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $("#fileupload1").val("");
})
```

When you assign an empty value to `FileUpload` it shows the default "No File Chosen" text.

Answer (score 0):

Take care fileupload1 looks like is an ASP.Net server-side FileUpload control.
so you should get its ID using the ClientID property, try this:

`var fu = document.getElementById("<%= fileupload1.ClientID %>");`